# How to implement Node.js app logging to CloudWatch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Node.js app docker container in aws ec2 instance, I want to use Cloudwatch Logs service for saving the logs of this node app.
I tried using [winston-aws-cloudwatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-aws-cloudwatch) npm package, but it's not working.Is there any other way to get my node app logs in cloudwatch?

Answer (score 0):

I tried some other package, please go through this

[lawgs](https://github.com/mentum/lawgs)